# Select tagName and tagValue from Xml

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

with a query in Sql Server 2008 I would like to extract **tagName** and **tagValue** from an xml, but I can only retrieve the tagValue.
I would like to extract them dynamically, because the tagnames could change

any help are appreciated

This is the code:

```
DECLARE @test AS XML='
<properties>
  <property key="FirstProp">Blah</property>
  <property key="SecondProp">Blah2</property>
  <property key="ThirdProp">Blah3</property>
  <property key="Other">80000011b</property>
  <property key="Another">TheEnd</property>
  <property key="MoreDIfficult">
    <structure type="">
      <property key="Id">10100</property>
      <property key="Name">TestName</property>
    </structure>
  </property>
</properties>
';

SELECT
    PROPERTY.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS TagName
    ,PROPERTY.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') AS TagValue
FROM
(SELECT CAST(@test AS XML) Prop  ) XML
OUTER APPLY XML.Prop.nodes('/properties/*') AS PROPERTY(N);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "tag name"? That appears to be working correctly, and is returning `'property'` in the `TagName` column.

Comment: Side Note: SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported over about 2.5 years. It is **strongly** recommended you upgrade to a supported version. The longer you don't do this, the harder it becomes to get onto a supported version.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a **desired output**.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It will retrieve any XML element that has a leaf child node as a text.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @test AS XML=
N'<properties>
  <property key="FirstProp">Blah</property>
  <property key="SecondProp">Blah2</property>
  <property key="ThirdProp">Blah3</property>
  <property key="Other">80000011b</property>
  <property key="Another">TheEnd</property>
  <property key="MoreDIfficult">
    <structure type="">
      <property key="Id">10100</property>
      <property key="Name">TestName</property>
    </structure>
  </property>
</properties>';

SELECT N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS TagName
    ,  N.value('@*[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Attr
    , N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS TagValue
FROM
(SELECT CAST(@test AS XML) Prop  ) XML
OUTER APPLY XML.Prop.nodes('/properties//*[text()]') AS PROPERTY(N);
```

**Output**

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| TagName  |   Attr     | TagValue  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| property | FirstProp  | Blah      |
| property | SecondProp | Blah2     |
| property | ThirdProp  | Blah3     |
| property | Other      | 80000011b |
| property | Another    | TheEnd    |
| property | Id         | 10100     |
| property | Name       | TestName  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```